# render different icons depending on boolean props inside a tooltip

Tags: reactjs

so i have this situation which i have a bar that map over data and renders an boxes with some icons, and each of them has it boolean prop that defines if the icons should be rendered.

**BoxBar.tsx** map over some data and renders a single box component, like so:

```
  const renderSingleBox = (item: any) => {
    return (
      <SingleBox
        subsystem={item.subsystem}
        serviceState={item.serviceState}
        isSimulatorMode={item.isSimulatorMode}
      />
    );
  };

  const renderIconBoxes = () => (
    <Wrapper>{data.map(item => renderSingleBox(item))}</Wrapper>
  );
```

---

**SingleBox.tsx** renders some icons,
like so:

```
  const renderIconBox = () => {
    return (
      <IconBox>
        <Tooltip message="Test" position={Position.Bottom} asPortal={true} cursor="pointer">
          {isSimulatorMode && <SimulatorModeIcon />}
          {isRemoteMode && <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faWifiSlash} size="sm" fontSize={16} />}
          {isServiceMode && <ServiceIcon />}
          {isResetIconVisible && (
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUndo} size="sm" fontSize={16} color={colors.primary} />
          )}
        </Tooltip>
      </IconBox>
    );
  };
```

But i need the `Tooltip` component to display the text `message` corresponding to the prop name itself,
for example, if the prop `isSimulatorMode` is true and the icon is displayed, the `Tooltip` should render the `message` **isSimulatorMode**

I hope its clear what i'm trying to get here.

I was thinking of maybe create a Map, something like this:

```
const MapPropsToElements = new Map<string, JSX.Element>([
  ["isSimulatorMode", <SimulatorModeIcon />],
  ["isRemoteMode", <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faWifiSlash} size="sm" fontSize={16} />],
  ["isServiceMode", <ServiceIcon />],
  [
    "isResetIconVisible",
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUndo} size="sm" fontSize={16} color={colors.primary} />
  ]
]);
```

but still i don't know how to iterate on it and render it correctly.

any ideas?
can i create a dynamic map that renders icons ?

thanx

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like

`const icons = [{name: 'isSimulatorMode', icon: <SimulatorModeIcon />}, {name: 'isServiceMode', icon: <ServiceIcon />}, ... ]`